# How to exit the UEFI shell from 'startup.nsh'

Tags: uefi

When *startup.nsh* is called automatically at start up, calling `exit` inside the script does only exit from the script, but not the shell. But I´d like to exit the shell.

When I call the same script after start up—just the normal way from shell with `startup.nsh`—it exits the shell as expected.

Calling other scripts from an automatically-called script at start up with `exit` cmd does not work neither.

`ver` gives me:

EFI Specification Revision: 2.40 
EFI Vendor:                 American Megatrends 
EFI Revision:               5.10

Comment: You can't. `exit` command only exits to parent (shell or script). Try setting appropriate boot order and rebooting from the script if it helps

Comment: UEFI Spec 2.2 says: "This command exits the UEFI Shell or, if /b is specified, the current script."
That´s why I think it should exit the shell, no matters where the `exit` cmd is called from.

Today I tried it again and it worked fine. Don´t know what I have changed. I will report when I found any reason/change.

Comment: OK, I found the difference why it worked one day and the other not: I used different bootx64.efi files. The one which does not exit the shell I have added to my question. The other one which does exit the shell was one I compiled with EDKII and gives me when calling `ver`:
UEFI Interactive Shell v2.2  
EDK II  
UEFI v2.4 (American Megatrends)